# I keep getting syntax error when using def on python

Tags: python, function

NOTE: This is a very basic game i am working on as a practice project i get a syntax error when defining explosions ( near the end of the code list... also i am very new to programming so yeah... if anyone could help that would be great i am stuck because i am new so your help is more than appreciated

```
import pygame, aya, random
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Timer

#set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#set up the window
WINDOW_WIDTH = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode ( (WINDOW_WIDTH,
WINDOW_HEIGHT),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Get Home!!")

#set up color constants
BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#set winning text
textFont = pygame.font.sysFont ("impact", 60)
text = textFont.render ("Welcome Home!", True, (193, 0, 0))

#set up the player and breadcrumbs
mapCounter = 0
NEW_GHOST = 20
GHOST_SIZE = 64
playerImage = pygame.image.load("playerimage.jpg")
playerImageTwo = pygame.image.load("playerimage.jpg")
ghostImage = pygame.image.load("ghost image.jpg")
ghostImageTwo = pygame.image.load("ghost image2.jpg")

player = pygame.Rect (300, 100,40, 40)
ghost = []
for i in range(20):
    ghost.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH - GHOST_SIZE),
                             random.randint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - GHOST_SIZE),
                             GHOST_SIZE, GHOST_SIZE))
#movement variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveDown = False

MOVE_SPEED = 6

#run the game loop
startGame = True
while startgame == True:
    #check for quit
    for event in pygame.event.get () :
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #keyboard variables
             if event.key ++ K_LEFT:
                 moveRight = False
                 moveLeft = True
             if event.key ++ K_RIGHT:
                 moveRight = False
                 moveLeft = False
             if event.key ++ K_UP:
                 moveUp = True
                 moveDown = False

             if event.key ++ K_DOWN:
                 moveUp = False
                 moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                ays.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveUP = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False

    ghostCounter += 1
    if ghostcounter >= NEW_GHOST:
        #clear ghost array and add new ghost
        ghostCounter = 0
        ghost.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH - GHOST_SIZE),
                                 random.randint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - GHOST_SIZE),
                                 GHOST_SIZE, GHOST_SIZE))
    #draw black background
        windowSurface.fill(BLACK)

        #move player
        if moveDown and play.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            player.top += MOVE_SPEED
        if moveUp and play.top > 0:
            player.top -= MOVE_SPEED                         
        if moveleft and play.left > 0:
            player.left -= MOVE_SPEED                         
        if moveRight and play.right < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            player.right += MOVE_SPEED


        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, player)
        for ghost in ghosts:
            windowSurface.blit(ghostImage, ghost)

        #check if player has intersected with ghost
        for ghost in ghosts[:]:

            if player.colliderect(ghost):
                windowSurface.blit(ghostImageTwo,ghost


                def explosion():
                     for ghost in ghosts:
                         if player.colliderect(ghost) and (moveLeft == False and
                              moveRight == False and moveUp == False and
                             moveDown == False):
                                 ghosts.remove(ghost)
                if player.colliderect(ghost) and (moveLeft == false and
            moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False): 
                     t = Timer(3, explosion)
                     t.start()

            if len(ghost == 0:
                ghostCounter = 0
                windowSurface.blit(text, (90, 104))
                startgame = False

            #draw the window
            pygame.display.update()
            mainClock.tick(40)

        while startgame == False
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?  Is all of this code really relevant?

Comment: You are missing a `)` here `windowSurface.blit(ghostImageTwo,ghost`. Consider upgrading your text editor to something that is compatible with Python so it will highlight such errors for you.

Comment: You're also missing a `)` in `if len(ghost == 0:`
and a `:` in `while startgame == False`

Answer (score 2):

As @BurhanKhalid pointed out, you are missing `)` at the end of line 111 (`windowSurface.blit(ghostImageTwo,ghost`), which is causing the error you noticed.

Additionally, you have **numerous** syntax errors.  You define variables in a different case than you use them (`startGame` being used as `startgame`, you forget to close several other `)`s (line 124, etc).  The list goes on.

Python is a forgiving language, but not that forgiving.  Find an editor and use it, learn how to debug your code, and stop being sloppy.  You will be unable to write code that works otherwise.

Comment: Good eye. I really make a poor python linter in the morning.